# Baking Shadows onto textures in Cycles Renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I'm trying to bake a lightmap in Cycles Renderer to a texture.

[image: screenshot]

The problem is it only bakes Ambient Occlusion properly, but no shadows.
You can see in the screenshot to the left that in the Rendered Preview there are some hard shadows, but when I bake that object to an image the shadows are gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU) is a video about cycles baking from blender guru which can be usefull in this situation.

Comment: @Shams hei man, thank you for the link. I watched all of it, but nothing about shadow setup :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

I had a *glass* object that I hidden in the scene. I had to move it away from between the lamp and the target mesh.